# Use \pgfplotsinvokeforeach (or \foreach) variable as macro

Tags: pgfplots, loops

I have some tables that I want to read and plot, each of them with their own style. For the sake of convenience, I like using the same tags. Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{tabA.dat}
x   y
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{tabB.dat}
x   y
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
tabA/.style={color=red,mark=*},
tabB/.style={color=black,mark=o},
}

\pgfplotstableread{tabA.dat}\tabA
\pgfplotstableread{tabB.dat}\tabB

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[legend,legend pos=south east]
            \addplot[tabA] table[x=x,y=y] {\tabA};\label{pgf:tabA}\addlegendentry{tabA}
            \addplot[tabB] table[x=x,y=y] {\tabB};\label{pgf:tabB}\addlegendentry{tabB}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

May I achieve the same result using `\pgfplotsforeachinvoke` or `\foreach`? Something like

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[legend,legend pos=south east]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{tabA,tabB}{%
            % The following doesn't work, of course
            \addplot[#1] table[x=x,y=y] {\#1}; % <- Magic goes here 
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Of course in this simple case I could simple use

```latex
\addplot[#1] table[x=x,y=y] {#1.dat};
```

but sometimes the name of the file does not follow a pattern or other times I just want to read and store a table in order to modify it or reuse it several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! One thing is always possible:

1. writing a macro that assembles a token list the way you want (here, concatenates a series of `\addplot` commands with appropriate options);
2. then using a second macro (in my code, constructed from the second argument of `\foreachTable`) that outputs something like `\begin{axis}[...]#1\end{axis}`, with `#1` replaced by the previously-assembled token list that contains all the `\addplot` commands.

This technique *always works* (once the second macro has been expanded, the TeX input stream is exactly in the same state as if you had entered all the code manually). You can therefore use it to programmatically generate tables, pictures, whatever you want.

Full code:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{tabA.dat}
x   y
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{tabB.dat}
x   y
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__millo_plot_cmds_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \millo_foreach_table_do_axis:nNn #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l__millo_plot_cmds_tl
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}
      {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#3}
        \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{myTable} } { \c{##1} } \l_tmpa_tl
        \tl_put_right:NV \l__millo_plot_cmds_tl \l_tmpa_tl
      }

    \exp_args:No #2 \l__millo_plot_cmds_tl
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \foreachTable { m m m }
  {
    \cs_set_protected:Npn \__millo_axis_func:n ##1 {#2}
    \millo_foreach_table_do_axis:nNn {#1} \__millo_axis_func:n {#3}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\pgfplotsset{
  tabA/.style={color=red,mark=*},
  tabB/.style={color=black,mark=o},
}

\pgfplotstableread{tabA.dat}\tabA
\pgfplotstableread{tabB.dat}\tabB

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreachTable{tabA, tabB}
    {
      \begin{axis}[legend, legend pos=south east]
        #1
      \end{axis}
    }
    { \addplot[#1] table[x=x,y=y] {\myTable}; \addlegendentry{#1} }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Explanation of the call:

```latex
\foreachTable{tabA, tabB}
  {
    \begin{axis}[legend, legend pos=south east]
      #1
    \end{axis}
  }
  { \addplot[#1] table[x=x,y=y] {\myTable}; \addlegendentry{#1} }
```

The first argument is the list of entries (each entry leads to one `\addplot` command).

The second argument is what will be inserted after the `#1` inside it has been replaced by the automatically-generated `\addplot` commands.

The third argument specifies the code for each automatically-generated plot, with some convenient replacements:

- `#1` replaced with the entry name (here: `tabA` then `tabB`);
- `\myTable` replaced with the control sequence token built from the entry name (here: `\tabA` for the first entry, `\tabB` for the second one).

If you want to manually add more plots (here, one before and one after the automatically-generated ones), you can for instance do:

```latex
\foreachTable{tabA, tabB}
  {
    \begin{axis}[legend, legend pos=south east]
      \addplot {sin(deg(\x))}; \addlegendentry{$\sin$}
      #1
      \addplot {sqrt(\x)};     \addlegendentry{$x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$}
    \end{axis}
  }
  { \addplot[#1] table[x=x,y=y] {\myTable}; \addlegendentry{#1} }
```

[image]

## For people who don't have `\regex_replace_all:nnN`

If your `l3kernel` is too old to have `\regex_replace_all:nnN`, you can:

- add `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { Nno }` before `\cs_new_protected:Npn \millo_foreach_table_do_axis:nNn #1#2#3`;
- replace the line

  ```latex
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{myTable} } { \c{##1} } \l_tmpa_tl
  ```

  with

  ```latex
  \exp_args:NNno
  \tl_replace_all:Nno \l_tmpa_tl { \myTable } { \use:c {##1} }
  ```

Then it should work **at the condition** that you don't use `\myTable` inside braces. For instance, use

```latex
\foreachTable{tabA, tabB}
  {
    ...
  }
  { \addplot[#1] table[x=x,y=y] \myTable; \addlegendentry{#1} }
```

instead of:

```latex
\foreachTable{tabA, tabB}
  {
    ...
  }
  { \addplot[#1] table[x=x,y=y] {\myTable}; \addlegendentry{#1} }
```

Comment: I used to think it could have been more straight-forward. Thanks!
I wasn't able to make it work on the PC I am working on (Debian with no root permission and TL 2015. It seems that it does not know the `\regex...` command, hence, `\myTable` could not be defined), but I tried it on some online compilers and it die work like a charm! I'll see if I can install a local more recent version of TL.
Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help. I added a workaround for people who don't have `\regex_replace_all:nnN` (cf. end of the answer). This doesn't imply that there isn't something *else* that is too old in your installation, though. :-)

Comment: Working seamlessly thanks to the edit! Thank you for the follow up!